# Add button to close panel

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to add a close button to close a `panel` that appears in the browser. For that I have a `javascript` file that launches the `prompt.html` file that is my `panel`.

```
var panel = require('sdk/panel').Panel({
    width  : 400,
    height : 400,
    contentURL : self.data.url('prompt.html')
});
```

Then in my `prompt.html` I have the following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>MyPanel</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="util.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    <body class="din">
        <h1>MyPanel</h1>
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2"></div>
    </body>
```

The script contains code to add nodes to the `div` and display a content. My question is : how can I add a button to close the panel ?

Comment: @KD Looks like the Mozilla Add-On SDK. Edit: [yep](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel)

Comment: take a look at http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html

Comment: Well as per my understanding there is no provision to add button to close the panel. all it has a even which you can register to handle hiding. Try to add a button inside your prompt.html itself and then call hide() method and check.

Comment: @EvilEpidemic in your example you manipulate windows not panels...

Comment: @KD you mean I add a button after the divs in the html body ? But shouldn't it be complicated to place it inside the window then ?

Comment: What is exactly a panel for you ? A popup ?

Comment: @SébastienGicquel yes a popup

Comment: Here's a non-sdk way of adding panne; and double clicking it closes, so you can use that double click code on an element: https://gist.github.com/yajd/9476471

Comment: @Noitidart isn't that for dynamically adding iframes inside panels ??

Comment: Yes but it adds the panel first. you can ignore the iframe part, this snippet here is more simplified, doesnt deal with iframe too much: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9445992 it inserts panel at full screen height so double click the panel to close/remove it. o that reminds me, in these snippets im actually removing the panel from the document, you may just want to use `hidePopup()` function instead of `removeNode` like i do in these two snippets.

Comment: Yes but what I would like to do is add the close button on the panel to have something that looks like this http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/ (click on the third or fourth button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a button to your panel.
2. On click, `self.port.emit` some message telling your `main.js` code to hide the panel.
3. Upon receiving the message, call `panel.hide()`.

### Working example

#### `main.js`

```
var self = require("sdk/self");

var panel = require('sdk/panel').Panel({
  width  : 400,
  height : 400,
  contentURL : self.data.url('prompt.html'),
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url('prompt.js')
});

// On "close" messages from the content script...
panel.port.on("close", function() {
  console.log("asked to close");
  // hide/close the panel.
  panel.hide();
});

// Initially show the panel for testing purposes.
panel.show();
```

#### `prompt.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MyPanel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a id="close_button">close</a>
    </div>
    <h1>MyPanel</h1>
    <div id="div1">div1</div>
    <div id="div2">div2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### `prompt.js`

```
// Wire-up an on click event listener.
document.getElementById("close_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Emit a "close" message to main.
  self.port.emit("close");
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain What is self ?

Comment: `self` is a helper object in content scripts, which you e.g. can use to [communicate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts#Accessing_port_in_the_content_script).

Comment: is just for separating prompt.js and prompt.html ?

Comment: I didn't get that question...?

Comment: the only change you made in my code is adding the two lines contentURL : self.data.url('prompt.html'),
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url('prompt.js') so I supposed self is only used to manage javascript code and html code in two separated files ...

Comment: Well, and I added a "button" to your html and all of `prompt.js`. `self` is available in content scripts, but not in inline/linked scripts in `contentURL` (as `contentURL` could point to a regular website, and regular websites should not have access to add-on stuff).

Comment: Yes but I still have a question : where should I tell the main to close the window onCLick ? Should I do something like  <a id="close" onClick="close_button">close</a> ?

Comment: The event listener in `prompt.js` reacts on clicking the "button" already. The example is a complete example which can be `cfx run`.